# Client VPN Endpoint - Use IPV4 address instead of cpvn hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn-client

Is it possible to get the IPV4 address for a client vpn endpoint?
If so, is it then possible to associate an elastic IP to the client vpn endpoint?

The router I am configuring as a vpn client only accepts IPV4 addresses for the server.

The Less ideal solution would be to use whatever the dynamic IPV4 address is associated to the endpoint.
The more ideal solution would be to have an elastic IP associated to the end point.

Comment: I've not read anything about being able to assign an elastic IP. You could try resolving the domain name to an IP, just be aware it could change at any time - though I suspect changes will be somewhat rare. It could be that domain name resolves to multiple pieces of hardware and you all end up on the same Amazon owned server / device.